# I get Segmentation Fault on running the following program in C

Tags: c

The following program is written in C
IDE : Code::Blocks 16.01

Question : Write a program to find difference of two dates in years,months and dates. Dates are in valid range and first date falls before second.

```
 //To find difference of two dates in years,months and dates, Dates are  in valid range and first date falls before second.

#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
int d,d1,d2,m,m1,m2,y,y1,y2;
printf("Enter first date (dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d,&d1,&m1,&y1");
printf("Enter the second date (dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d,&d2,&m2,&y2");
if(d2<d1)
{
    if(m2==3)
    {
        if (y2%100!=0 && y2%4==0|| y2%400==0) // Checking leap year
            d2+=29;
        else
            d2+=28;

    }
    else if (m2==5||m2==7||m2==10||m2==12)
        d2+=30;
    else
        d2+=31;

}
if (m2<m1)
{
    y2=y2-1;
    m2+=12;
}
y=y2-y1;
d=d2-d1;
m=m2-m1;
printf("Difference of the two dates is : ");
printf("%d years,%d months,%d days\n",y,m,d);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d/%d/%d,&d1,&m1,&y1");` --> `scanf("%d/%d/%d",&d1,&m1,&y1);`

Comment: The question is vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d,&d1,&m1,&y1");
```

and

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d,&d2,&m2,&y2");
```

are wrong you must read the manual of [`scanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

The first argument is the format string `"%d/%d/%d"` and you must pass each address after: `&d1, &m1, &y1`.

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &d1, &m1, &y1);
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &d2, &m2, &y2);
```

You should verify the return value of function:

```
if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &d1, &m1, &y1) != 3) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Something go wrong!");
  return 1;
}
```